# Search and replace in Vim across all the project files

Tags: vim, replace

I'm looking for the best way to do search-and-replace (with confirmation) across all project files in Vim. By "project files" I mean files in the current directory, some of which do not have to be open.

One way to do this could be to simply open all of the files in the current directory:

```
:args ./**
```

and then do the search and replace on all open files:

```
:argdo %s/Search/Replace/gce
```

However, when I do this, Vim's memory usage jumps from a couple dozen of MB to over 2 GB, which doesn't work for me.

I also have the [EasyGrep](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2438) plugin installed, but it almost never works—either it doesn't find all the occurrences, or it just hangs until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. So far my preferred way to accomplish this task it to [ack-grep](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) for the search term, using it's quickfix window open any file that contains the term and was not opened before, and finally `:bufdo %s/Search/Replace/gce`.

I'm looking either for a good, working plugin that can be used for this, or alternatively a command/sequence of commands that would be easier than the one I'm using now.

Comment: @Cascabel Since you wrote this comment, there is a vi.stackexchange.com site.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Greplace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1813) works well for me.

There's also a [pathogen ready version](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Greplace.vim) on github.

Comment: Installed it, I see the other commands like `:Gsearch` and `:Gbuffersearch` exist, but when I type `:Greplace` I get `Not an editor command: Greplace`.

Comment: according to the docs, the syntax is:
`:Gsearch [<grep-option(s)>] [[<pattern>] [<filename(s)>]]`

so you could do a recursive search using, for example:
`:Gsearch -r pattern dir/`

Comment: The thing I hate about Greplace is that if the pattern is in the filename, Greplace fails, because you end up replacing it in the filename, too.

Comment: Nothing unusual here after 6 years, but this plugin is severely outdated in comparison to some new answers (https://github.com/yegappan/greplace) last update, 3+ years ago. I might check out the builtin solution by Sid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38004355/2224331 (It's not me on another account, just a coincidence :P)

Answer (score 120):

The other big option here is simply not to use vim:

```
sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/' <files>
```

or if you have some way of generating a list of files, perhaps something like this:

```
find . -name *.cpp | xargs sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/'
grep -rl 'pattern1' | xargs sed -i 's/pattern2/replacement/'
```

and so on!

Comment: Thanks!  I really need to learn this old school command line stuff.  I think this is the best answer.  Are these regexes perl regexes or vim regexes or some other kind of regex?

Comment: @EricJohnson: They're... `sed` regexes, which are essentially POSIX.2 basic regular expressions, but not exactly (this is in the manpage) -  they let `\n` match newlines, and some other similar things. They're therefore pretty much the same as `grep` regular expressions.

Comment: Is there a reason you have -i in the sed command? The man page says that is for specifying an extension, but you don't appear to actually specify one.

Comment: Ok it actually looks like 's/pattern/replacement/' is the extension, I think I understand now.

Comment: @davekaro Sorry, missed those comments before. I think you've misread the manpage. `-i` means "in place" - it makes sed change the contents of the files instead of printing the result to stdout. If you provide an argument for it, it's used as a file extension for backup files (in place actually means write to backup file then move that over the original). But `sed -i 's/.../.../'` is not parsed as an argument for `-i` on any system I"ve used. The `'s/.../.../` is just the command.

Comment: On Mac OS X the only sed command that worked for me was: `find . -type f | LANG=C xargs sed -i '' 's/SEARCH/REPLACE/g'`

Comment: In case your file names contain spaces, you can add another `sed` transformation that replaces beginning and end of lines with double quotes (thus, making the names safe to pass along) like so: `grep -rl 'pattern1' | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | xargs sed -i 's/pattern2/replacement/'`

Comment: I would rate this as the best command I ever ran on Unix - simply brilliant: sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/' *

Answer (score 94):

**EDIT: Use `cfdo` command instead of `cdo` to significantly reduce the amount of commands that will be run to accomplish this** (because `cdo` runs commands on each element while `cfdo` runs commands on each file)

Thanks to the recently added [`cdo` command](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/aa23b379421aa214e6543b06c974594a25799b09), you can now do this in two simple commands using whatever `grep` tool you have installed. No extra plugins required!:

```
1. :grep <search term>
2. :cdo %s/<search term>/<replace term>/gc
3. (If you want to save the changes in all files) :cdo update
```

(`cdo` executes the given command to each term in the quickfix list, which your `grep` command populates.)

(Remove the `c` at the end of the 2nd command if you want to replace each search term without confirming each time)

Comment: Plus you can add ````:cdo update```` to save the changes in all files.

Comment: But it will pauses to warn not saved each time before switching to the next buffer when current buffer is modified.

Comment: @Zhe thanks, I've added that to the answer; @lfree I personally prefer confirming each change, but you can remove the `c` at the end of the second command (just use `g`) to have it search and replace without asking for confirmation

Comment: For `cdo`, the range `%` is not necessary. It's needed only when using `cfdo`.

Comment: This should be the new answer. Works perfectly and no need for plugins.

Comment: :cdo %s/search term/replace term/g  only replace the first occurence, but does not work for the second occurrence in my vim

Comment: Since command 2. above (running `cdo`) depends on the correct `grep` command to populate the quickfix list, it may help to ensure that the `grep` command produced desired output by looking at the quickfix window (*tip:* `:copen`).

Comment: Is there a way to automatically save the file after the search and replace? I run into the same problem as @lfree

Comment: for using `update`, I had to: `cdo %s/<search term>/<replace term>/g | update`

Comment: I recommend doing `:cdo .s/` so that you only replace the lines returned by the grep. Otherwise if you don't want to do a match you need to say `n` to it once for each match in the file. If you want to do a global search on the file you can do `:cfdo %s/` so that you search and replace globally but it only ones once-per-file.

Comment: @KevinCox I didn't understand your comment until I attempted to do this myself. using %s instead of .s will not only try to match the line from the quickfix list, once the file is open, it will globally match every instance in that file. Once that is finished, it picks up the next line from the quickfix list. And the cycle starts again, so if you can imagine this being problematic if you had 10 matches in one file and only wanted to change two of them. You would search that same file at LEAST 10 times

Comment: @KevinCox thanks I updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: @Sid Thanks. Why not just replace the command in the answer though? I don't see why you would prefer `:cdo %` over `:cfdo %` or `:cdo .`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I used :cdfo in neovim and replaced a string in about 25 files in a single project with minimal amounts of messing around with opening and closing buffers required from my part. Any no additional plugins required!

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Should definitely be accepted.

Answer (score 36):

I've decided to use ack and Perl to solve this problem in order to take advantage of the more powerful full Perl regular expressions rather than the GNU subset.

```
ack -l 'pattern' | xargs perl -pi -E 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

## Explanation

### ack

[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) is an awesome command line tool that is a mix of `grep`, `find`, and full Perl regular expressions (not just the GNU subset).  Its written in pure Perl, its fast, it has syntax highlighting, works on Windows and its friendlier to programmers than the traditional command line tools.  Install it on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install ack-grep`.

### xargs

[Xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) is an old unix command line tool.  It reads items from standard input and executes the command specified followed by the items read for standard input.  So basically the list of files generated by ack are being appended to the end of the `perl -pi -E 's/pattern/replacemnt/g'` command.

### perl -pi

Perl is a programming language.  The -p option causes Perl to create a loop around your program which iterates over filename arguments.  The -i option causes Perl to edit the file in place.  You can modify this to create backups.  The -E option causes Perl to execute the one line of code specified as the program.  In our case the program is just a Perl regex substitution.  For more information on Perl command line options [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).  For more information on Perl see http://www.perl.org/.

Comment: I like this answer because it works even with cygwin's line endings. Note that it does add a \r to the end of modified lines, but when using sed, it will replace *every* newline, making your diffs unusable. Perl is a bit more sane, and this is a really great one-liner for search and replace. Thanks!

Comment: @andrew, I'm not sure exactly whats going wrong in your case.  Would it help you to use \R instead of \n in your regexps?  See \R section in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc.  Also try http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions.  Perl is extremely cross platform and I'm sure there is a way for you to not end up with mangled line endings.

Comment: My regex doesn't have any newlines in it, the cygwin versions of these programs automatically add \r at the end of each line modified. I specifically liked the perl version because it only modifies the lines it matches whereas sed will modify *all* lines, even if they don't match the regex.

Comment: What if the file's path contains spaces?

Answer (score 25):

maybe do this:

```
:noautocmd vim /Search/ **/*
:set hidden
:cfirst
qa
:%s//Replace/gce
:cnf
q
1000@a
:wa
```

Explanation:

- `:noautocmd vim /Search/ **/*` ⇒ lookup (`vim` is an abbreviation for `vimgrep`) pattern in all files in all subdirectories of the cwd without triggering autocmds (`:noautocmd`), for speed's sake.
- `:set hidden` ⇒ allow having modified buffers not displayed in a window (could be in your vimrc)
- `:cfirst`  ⇒ jump to first search result
- `qa`  ⇒ start recording a macro into register *a*
- `:%s//Replace/gce` ⇒ replace all occurrences of the last search pattern (still `/Search/` at that time) with `Replace`:

  - several times on a same line (`g` flag)
  - with user confirmation (`c` flag)
  - without error if no pattern found (`e` flag)
- `:cnf` ⇒ jump to next file in the list created by the `vim` command
- `q` ⇒ stop recording macro
- `1000@a` ⇒ play macro stored in register a 1000 times
- `:wa` ⇒ save all modified buffers

*** EDIT *** Vim 8 way:

Starting with Vim 8 there is a better way to do it, as `:cfdo` iterates on all files in the quickfix list:

```
:noautocmd vim /Search/ **/*
:set hidden
:cfdo %s//Replace/gce
:wa
```

Comment: you might want to explaing that a bit further for us lesser mortals. It's not clear to me if you need to do this "sequence" every time. I'm faster doing that using my rusty old Delphi 5 so surely I must be missing something.

Comment: @Lieven: You are right, this is a bit obscure without comments. I will develop some explanation.

Comment: +1 but although `vim` has won me over for many things, I think I'll stick to PowerGrep with this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation of all of the commands, I really appreciate it. I'm accepting the other answer because I prefer to use a plugin for this.

Comment: I've marked this down because it causes more confusion, given the disparity between the level of someone asking the question and the level required to understand this answer.

Comment: This is the right answer because the question literally says "in vim" in the title.

Comment: Good answer, this is in vim and you can create your own command in vimrc with all those lines to simplify.

Answer (score 23):

### Populate `:args` from a shell command

It's possible (on some operating systems<sup>1</sup>)) to supply the files for `:args` via a shell command.

For example, if you have ack<sup>2</sup> installed,

```
:args `ack -l pattern`
```

will ask ack to return a list of files containing 'pattern' and put these on the argument list.

Or with plain ol' grep i guess it'd be:

```
:args `grep -lr pattern .`
```

You can then just use `:argdo` as described by the OP:

```
:argdo %s/pattern/replacement/gce
```

### Populate `:args` from the quickfix list

Also check out [nelstrom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686810/2004045) to a related question describing a simple user defined command that populates the arglist from the current quickfix list.  This works great with many commands and plugins whose output ends up in the quickfix list (`:vimgrep`, `:Ack`<sup>3</sup>, `:Ggrep`<sup>4</sup>).

The sequence to perform a project wide search could then be done with:

```
:vimgrep /pattern/ **/*
:Qargs 
:argdo %s/findme/replacement/gc
```

where `:Qargs` is the call to the user defined command that populates the arglist from the quickfix list.

You'll also find links in the [ensuing discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686810/2004045) to simple plugins that get this workflow down to 2 or 3 commands.

### Links

1. **:h {arglist}** - vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#{arglist}
2. **ack** - [betterthangrep.com/](http://betterthangrep.com/)
3. **ack.vim** -  [github.com/mileszs/ack.vim](http://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim)
4. **fugitive** -  [github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive](http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)

Comment: argdo stops after the first file with a write problem

Answer (score 9):

One more option in 2016, [far.vim](https://github.com/brooth/far.vim) plugin:

[image: far.vom]

Comment: You should also say that you are the author of the plugin :)

Answer (score 6):

```
1. :grep <search term> (or whatever you use to populate the quickfix window)
2. :cfdo %s/<search term>/<replace term>/g | update
```

Step 1 populates the quickfix list with items you want. In this case, it's propagated with search terms you want to change via `grep`.

`cfdo` runs the command following on each file in the quickfix list. Type `:help cfdo` for details.

`s/<search term>/<replace term>/g` replaces each term. `/g` means replace every occurrence in the file.

`| update` saves the file after every replace.

I pieced this together based upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004355/26604) and its comments, but felt it deserved its own answer since it's all in one place.

Comment: For me on NeoVim, a slight modification needed to be done in the line 2 above:
`2. :cfdo %s/<search term>/<replace term>/g | update`
Without the `%`, only the first occurrence of the pattern is replaced.

Comment: Thanks Kareem. I updated the answer since `%s` works on regular vim too.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind of introducing external dependency, I have brewed a plugin [ctrlsf.vim](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) (depends on [ack](https://github.com/petdance/ack2) or [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)) to do the job.

It can format and display search result from ack/ag, and synchronize your changes in result buffer to actual files on disk.

Maybe following demo explains more

[image: ctrlsf_edit_demo]

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you’re using Neovim (or Vim 7.4.8+, but really just use Neovim)
2. Install FZF for the command line and as a vim plugin
3. Install Ag, so that it’s available automatically to FZF in vim
4. If using iTerm2 on OSX, set the alt/option key to Esc+

Usage

Search the text you want to change in the current directory and it’s children with

`:Ag text`

- Keep typing to fuzzy filter items
- Select items with alt-a
- Deselect items with alt-d
- Enter will populate the quickfix list
- :cfdo %s/text/newText/g | :w

Now you have chabges made inside Vim NeoVim

[source](https://elliotec.com/how-to-find-and-replace-in-project-with-vim/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with shell and vim's ex-mode. This has the added benefit of not needing to memorize other search-and-replace escape sequences.

Any command that can list files will work (`rg -l`, `grep -rl`, `fd`...). For example in bash:

```sh
for f in $(rg -l Search); do
vim -Nes "$f" <<EOF
%s/Search/Replace/g
wq
EOF
done
```

You can use any command, those prefixed with `:` in command mode, the same way you would inside vim, just drop the `:` at the start

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because you have a huge amount of files been captured in memory. For my case, I do this by group files in different types, for example:

```
:args **/*.md
argdo <command>

:args **/*.haml
argdo <command>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I wanted the replace in a single command and more importantly within vim itself

Based on the [answer by @Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824742/1520443) i've created a keyboard shortcut, which I had set in my .vimrc file like this

```
nmap <leader>r :!grep -r -l  * \| xargs sed -i -e 's///g'
```

now from the vim, on a stroke of leader+r I get the command loaded in vim, which i edit like below,

```
:!grep -r -l <find> <file pattern> | xargs sed -i -e 's/<find>/<replace>/g'
```

Hence, I do the replace with a single command and more importantly within vim itself

Comment: and i actually use ag instead of grep