# How can I do a search and replace across files in all subdirectories using vi?

Tags: vi

In `vi` editor, I understand the following line does a search and replace of all occurrences in a file:

```
:%s/search_string/replacement_string/g
```

How can I search a string across all files in all subdirectories (entire folder tree) and do a replace in all those files (with occurrences of search string)?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do this outside of vim, with sed:

```
find . -type f -name "*" | xargs sed -i "s/search_string/replacement_string/g"
```

will replace all instances of `search_string` with `replacement_string` in all files in and under the current directory.

OSX (BSD sed):

```
find . -type f -name "*" | xargs sed -i '' "s/search_string/replacement_string/g"
```

Note the extra empty string arg `sed -i '' "s/...`

Bonus: I often find it useful to search/replace interactively (with y/n prompt per replacement) across all files. Vim handles this beautifully:

```
for filename in $(find . -type f -name "*"); do vim -c "%s/search_string/replacement_string/gc" -c "wq" "${filename}"; done
```

Credit to all those that have answered this question in the past and helped me with countless refactors. [Search and replace in Vim across all the project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804405/search-and-replace-in-vim-across-all-the-project-files)